# Can't read properties of undefined React API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to build a loading component so that my app doesn't try and display my API data before it has loaded, causing a fatal error. Read a lot about `componentWillMount` function but this seems to have been deprecated. Trying to use setState to no avail.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Marquee from "react-fast-marquee";

const News = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const getNewsFromApi = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "API_KEY_HERE"
      );
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log("json", responseJson);
      setData(responseJson);
    };
    setLoading(false);
    setInterval(getNewsFromApi, 1000)
    
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <h1> Data is loading...</h1>
  }


  return (
    <div >
    
      <Marquee gradientColor="" speed="120">
        <h1>{data?.articles[0].title}  - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[1].title}  - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[2].title}  - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[3].title} - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[4].title} - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[5].title} - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[6].title} - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[7].title} - </h1>
        <h1>{data?.articles[8].title} - </h1>

      
      </Marquee>
    </div>


  )
}

export default News
```

Comment: What is the value of `data` before the load completes? It's not `undefined` or `null`. It's `{}`. So, what is the value of `data?articles`? It's `undefined` (i.e. **not** an array). So what is the value of `data?.articles[0]`? Boom.

Comment: `data` is set to the value you expect **after the data has loaded**. Before the data has loaded, its value is `{}` as set in the line `const [data, setData] = useState({});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` hook runs after the render (see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)). So what's going to happen:

1. You initialize `loading` as `false` (by calling `useState(false)`).
2. Component renders first time with `loading=false` so it skips loading placeholder and tries to immediately render articles list which is `{}`. It means `data?.articles` is `undefined`.

I would do the following changes:

1. Change your state declaration:

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

This will make component to render loading placeholder first time.
2. Using state as an array of articles instead of object that is returned from your API also makes sense (as @Bru No suggested). But you'll need to make changes in your effect - something like:

```js
setData(responseJson.articles);
```

Answer (score -1):

you start read infos from state before the api response i suggest to use this solution

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Marquee from "react-fast-marquee";

const News = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    (async function getNewsFromApi(){
      const response = await fetch(
        "API_KEY_HERE"
      );
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log("json", responseJson);
      setData(responseJson);
    })();
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <h1> Data is loading...</h1>
  }
  return (
    <div >
      <Marquee gradientColor="" speed="120">
        {data.length > 0 && data.articles.map((item)=> <h1>{item.title} </h1>)}
      </Marquee>
    </div>
  )
}

export default News
```

Comment: Thanks for your help however this solution still results in the same error on app startup

Comment: Did you initialize the state to empty array ?